# How to call API Gateway service inside the onSubmit function of dojo programmatic form?

Tags: dojo

I am trying to call the rest service inside the onSubmit: function() of DOJO programmatic form But, when i click on Submit button then it's not showing any alert values and Instead of showing alert data, it's refreshing the screen and going back to Home page. Here is the code which i have written

```
onSubmit: function() { 
   var repositoryID = this.repotextbox.get('value');
   xhr("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={repositoryID}",{ 
            // The URL of the request 
           method: "GET", 
            handleAs: "json", 

           /* data: { 
                  repoID: repositoryID, 
                  DFMKey: DFM-API-Key 
                  } */
            /*query: {
                city name: repositoryID
            }*/

           }).then(
              function(data){ 

                alert(data.success + " " + JSON.stringify(data)); 
              }, 
              function(err){ 
              alert( "Your message could not be sent, please try again."); 
              });
    },
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: The xhr will execute with a delay. But by that time, the submit has been executed and the browser shows a different page. Your handler has to return a value (`false`? don't remember exactly) to tell the browser not to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks Roland. Actually what i am doing is: I hava a class AddButtonEntryPoint.js and there i have written a code under onClick function to get the form after click on button as below: _onClick: function () {
   // Triggered when the button is clicked.
   var w = new Form({});
   
   var d = new Dialog({
    id: 'FormDialog',
    title: "Bridge Form",
    style: "width: 270px; height: 270px;",
    content: w,
    onHide: function() {
     // To prevent destroying the dialog before the animation ends
     setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, 'destroyRecursive'), 0);
    }
   }); d.show(); }

Comment: So I will get a form in a Dialog box after click on button and then at the time of Submitting the form I have written the above mentioned code under onSubmit function to call the service in another js file So, through that process it will call the service which i have mentioned under onSubmit function? If not, Can you please guide me how to call the service after click on Button .